# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql\Interceptor::getSchemaListener() after upgrading to 2.3.4

Tags: magento2.3.4, windows

I just upgraded to 2.3.4 and get this message after running `php bin/magento setup:db-data:upgrade`:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql\Interceptor::getSchemaListener() in C:\Sites\magento\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php:939
```

OS is Windows Server 2016, in case it helps. Thanks in advance!